# I there an online tool to convert HTML into a string?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there an online tool to convert HTML code line per line into a string by putting quotation marks around it? I nee HTML code as String to use it within a JS file in order to inject it into the DOM on demand.

String

```
"<div class=\"my\"> as a String </div>"
+"<img>"
```

Comment: HTML is just text, so it's already a string.  What exactly is the issue you're facing?

Comment: HTML is a string. Are you asking for something more specific?

Comment: I mean the quotations around it

Comment: So you have a html-document and want to insert it into a programming language like java, where a string over multiple lines must be connected with plus-signs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try with JS?

[HTML to JS (click)](http://www.accessify.com/tools-and-wizards/developer-tools/html-javascript-convertor/)